# How to destructure an array of IDs and pass them into use Selector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux, frontend

I'm quite new in JS and trying to figure out things (sry for a noob question). Let's say I have a selector in the Redux store that holds information about connected accounts from different providers:

```
const connnectedAccounts = useSelector(getConnectedAccounts);
```

I mapped client ids from the selector and got an array of client ids for each provider:

```
const clientIds = connnectedAccounts.map((el) => el.clientId);
```

Now I want to use that client ids in another selector to get list of items for each of them.
I tried to destructure the array:

```
const [clientId] = clientIds;
const itemsList = useSelector((getItemsByClientId(clientId)));
```

And this is the mistake and a problem for me. useSelector does not accept an array but a string instead, itemsList will not return items for each provider, but only the first one. I also tried to do this with reduce(), but failed.

How can I accomplish it?

Ideally, I would not need to create a new selector.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you apply the `useSelector` in a `map`, as you have done for `clientIds`? `clientIds.map((clientId) => useSelector(getItemsByClientId(clientId)));`

Comment: @gloo thanks for the response. No, I cannot do it  - ("React Hook "useSelector" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function")

Comment: That's right, I forgot about the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). I think you should write your selector and store such that you store all of your `clientId` items in an easily selectable slice of your store, since you will be retrieving info for multiple items at a time. There are some examples in the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#basic-selector-concepts)

Comment: Thank you. A new selector is not an option due to the rest of the logic, I'm curious if there is a way to do it as I intended :)

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want to create a new selector (which would be the best choice), you can search for existed selector that can return you all items and then select from them on your component side.

If you haven't any selectors that return all items, then you have no other option and you need to create a new selector

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the response. The problem is that the two selectors I used here are from different stores. So, I need to use client ids from one store and pass it as an argument to the selector from another store.

Comment: So you are struggling with passing client ids as an argument to selector? If yes, then just make your second selector looks like this `const someSelector = (clientIds) => (state) => *your code to select clients*` and then use it like you tried before `const itemsList = useSelector((getItemsByClientId(clientId)));`